# Why use case classes with Slick?

Tags: slick

I understand that Slick is not an ORM and therefore doesn't understand relationships. Given this, the slick Table classes pretty much mirror the underlying database tables e.g. they would include an addressId property, not an Address property. All this makes sense to me.

What I don't understand is why I would also use a case class if the case class must also mirror the table? Given the typical Person, Address example as I understand it I can't easily use:

```
case class Person(id: Option[Int], name: String, address: Option[Address])
```

because slick can't map from an addressId to an Option[Address] i.e.

```
class PersonTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "PERSON") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def addressId = column[Int]("address_id")
  def * = (id, name, addressId) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply) 
}
```

so I need to create a Person case class which looks like:

```
case class Person(id: Option[Int], name: String, address: Option[Int])
```

which is almost a mirror of PersonTable?

Answer (score 0):

Slick `Table`s are a complex, lifted type that you would not want to work with directly.  What you want to work with is a sequence of some "normal" scala type.  The `Person` case class you are creating is this "normal" scala type that you can use.  Think of it as your relational data finally escaping the relational model and ending up in Object Oriented land.